# Flink Checkpointing with S3, Network issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink cluster and I used checkpoint via S3,
Each minute I get a snapshot of the current state into S3 and it takes 20 seconde,
but the snapshot use all network bandwidth (1 Gb/s) so my job get 20 seconde of latency each minute.

My question is, there is a way to limit bandwidth of checkpoint or disable the full network usage by checkpoint or another solution ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already doing so, I recommend you look into using incremental checkpointing (with RocksDB). This feature was added in Flink 1.4, and has proven to be very helpful for Flink applications with large state.

Incremental checkpointing is turned off by default. To enable it, pass true to the constructor, like this

```
RocksDBStateBackend backend =
    new RocksDBStateBackend(filebackend, true);
```

or set `state.backend.incremental` to true in your config file.

This won't directly address what you asked -- how to throttle the checkpointing so it doesn't saturate the network -- but should help, nonetheless.

Also, note that [Amazon recommends using the Elastic Network Adapter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/) in applications that make heavy use of S3. This provides up to 25 Gbps of bandwidth.

For more on working with large state in Flink, you might want to look at

- [Managing Large State in Apache Flink®: An Intro to Incremental Checkpointing](https://data-artisans.com/blog/managing-large-state-apache-flink-incremental-checkpointing-overview) , Stefan Richter, data Artisans
- [Scaling Flink in Cloud](https://www.slideshare.net/FlinkForward/flink-forward-san-francisco-2018-steven-wu-scaling-flink-in-cloud), Steven Wu, Netflix

Comment: I'm using S3, but my flink cluster isn't in AWS and my provider don't have network band more than 1 Gb/s.